# How do I limit the text length limit for href

Tags: html, css, jsp, jsp-tags

```
 <c:forEach var="result" items="${resultList }" varStatus="status">
                <ul>

                    <li><a href="/board/notice.do?brdSn=${result.brdSn}">${result.brdTitle}</a><span class="date">${result.updDt }</span></li> 
                </ul>
</c:forEach>
```

let say I want to limit the length of ${result.brdTitle}. 
how to do it?

Comment: width, overflow, text-overflow...

Answer (score 0):

i limited the lenght of link using a small jquery function. You can use the class `link` where it is needed.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".link").each(function(i){
    len=$(this).text().length;
    if(len>10)
    {
      $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,10)+'...');
    }
  });       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="link">
Hello test test
</p>
```